# Getting HTML in the controller from view template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, templates

Stackoverflow has taught me so much about what proper RESTful, MVC, GET/POST is that I am wondering how people learn to program/engineer in the past before Stackoverflow existed.  ;)

Given that, here is another question on how I can do a (fairly) common procedure in the most appropriate way.

I need to generate a HTML from a view template to be used in a controller action. In that sense, it is kind of like ActiveMailer.

1. HTML template in a .html.erb file
2. Controller action with the params
3. Get the HTML from the template to use in the controller

What is the best way to that? Pseudo code will be very much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Perhaps I'm missing something, but do you just want render_to_string?

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html#M000465

```
foo = render_to_string(:template => 'foo/bar', :locals => { :something => 'value' })
```

That basically is the same as calling render on a template, but writes to a string (foo) rather than to the http response.

Comment: you can also specify `:layout => false` to not include the rails generated portion.